# Random post javascript in AMP

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script

```js
function showLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var entry = feed.entry[0];
      for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j) {
       if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
       window.location = entry.link[j].href;
       }
      }
   }

function fetchLuck(luck){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary/-/1 to 10?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }
function readLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
    var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    luckyNumber++;
    fetchLuck(luckyNumber);
    }
function feelingLucky(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary/-/1 to 10?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
//]]>
```

```css
.btn_tc {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.3em;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn_tc:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.green_tc {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_tc green_tc" href="#random" onclick="feelingLucky()" title="Random Post">Continue</a>
```

Which works properly in  NORMAL website. Loads a random post from a specific tag (label).

i'm trying to include this script to an AMP website through this method:

```
<script async='async' custom-element='amp-script' src='https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js'/>

<amp-script layout="container" src="https://mysite/random.js"></amp-script>
<a class="btn_tc green_tc" href="#random" title="Random Post">Continue</a>
```

Obviously is not working and i know that i'm missing something but i don't really know where to concentrate to make it work on AMP version.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your question. No errors but i think button and script are not connected at all. In my opinion i need to connect my script and the button by some id but i have no clear idea at this point. Any suggestion is welcomed.